# Issues with In-Links from a Baselined Module

Tags: ibm-doors

I have an Object with an in-link to a Baselined Module, the In-Link was Deleted in the Current Module (The outlink from the baselined Module was Deleted). When using the canDelete function it returns true thus giving a DXL error when using the softdelete function on that object.  The in-link should not exist and when opened it opens the Baseline Module. I.E. The inlinked module is 2.0 but when the inlink is opened the Baseline 1.0 is opened.  This is creating an issue in the application used for Object Management, how can this be avoided?  The canDelete function should return false since it has In-Links but it is returning True thus giving the error on softDelete.  I am currently running DOORS 9.3, I have not tested it yet in 9.5 but 9.5 is currently out of the question. How can this be fixed?

Comment: Just to clarify, are you saying the link you have is an out link from a baselined version of a document to a current version of this object in another module? You would not be able to delete a link in a baseline, so I am not sure what you are trying to do here. Maybe you could post a screenshot or some more information.

Comment: I need to delete an object, but cannot delete it because it has an inlink from a baselined module. I cannot delete that inlink because it comes from a baseline, in the current module of that baseline the outlink was deleted.

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing is intended functionality of the tool. Because the baslined document should not be altered, you can't delete an object it was linked to. The only way you will be able to remove the object is to baseline that module first. Then you should be able to delete the current object. There is no DXL method to get around this functionality.

Comment: So i need to do another baseline on the current module to remove the inlink from a baseline? Rigth now i have an object with 2 inlinks from the same object but one of those inlinks is from a baseline.

Comment: Are these documents part of a baseline set? When the set is completed the links that existed, now exist in the baselines and in the current documents separately. You would have a link from the baseline object to the baseline object in the other document, and a link from the current to the current in the other document. This link, the current one, can then be deleted. It sounds like you have a situation where one document has been baselined as part of the set, but the other has not yet been baselined.

Comment: Apparently that was the cause of the issue, thanks for the response.  The other part had not been baselined so there were duplicate links, one to the baseline and one to the current one.